# Can't figure out how to get access token using facebook c# sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I'm currently writing a Facebook app that runs in a page tab.  I'm writing it as a simple Web Forms app in C#, using the latest version of the C# SDK pulled from NuGet.  The main page tab works fine. I get all the info I need from FacebookWebContext.Current.SignedRequest, and I'm fine there.  I'm trying to write a page now that the page admin would use to set up the app, so this is the page that would go under the "Edit URL" in the app setup.

All I really want to do is get the currently signed-on user's ID, and determine if he's an admin for the page in question.

I'm doing this:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
```

in Page_Load, and getting the following exception:

```
(OAuthException) An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I've tried a bunch of stuff to get the access token, but I don't seem to know what I'm doing wrong.  Is there a straightforward way of doing this?

**Update:**
I figured out at one point that I had a reference to the old JS SDK on my master page, and that was causing a problem.  (See [here](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/faq/jssdk/jssdk_02.html)).  Removing that got me to the point where I was *usually* able to see whether or not the user was actually logged in to Facebook.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var fbContext = FacebookWebContext.Current;
if (fbContext.IsAuthenticated())
{
    var client = new FacebookClient(fbContext.AccessToken);
    dynamic me = client.Get("me");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've basically been doing variations on that.  My problem, I guess, is that IsAuthenticated() returns false, even though I'm logged in to Facebook, and the Edit URL page is being opened via the Facebook app settings link. Basically, I'm not sure how, in this context, to tell that the page is being opened by a logged-in Facebook user.  I've seen some indication that Facebook __used to__ pass in a signed_request to an "Edit URL" page, but it seems like they don't now.

Comment: In your facebook javascript init do you have `cookie: true` as one of the options? From my understanding, this is what allows the server to access the facebook session.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, being logged-in in Facebook does not mean `FacebookWebcontext.Current.isAuthenticated() == true`. What Facebook wants to make sure is that the user has authorized the app. So what you should do is to forward the page to facebook authorization dialogue page (https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?) with necessary permissions. Facebook will determine whether the app has been authorized by the user and redirect to the redirect_uri with a newer access_token issued.

Comment: Thanks for posting. I actually thought that what you're describing would apply to the IsAuthorized() call rather than the IsAuthenticated() call.  I'm working on a new web site with Facebook integration, and I'm facing this problem again.  (I gave up on it last time.) I'm finding now that, even when I am definitely logged in to Facebook, and have authorized the app, I still get a false return from both of these functions.